# How to test if composer.lock is up to date?

Tags: php, bash, composer-php

During development (multiple people in the team) sometimes `composer install` returns:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
> composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to
> update them.

Is there a way to check for this very quickly (in milliseconds, without making any changes)?

I understand how composer works. However when code merges in it doesn't necessarily cause merge conflicts on the `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file and it's not fun to run `composer install` all the time when there's almost never any changes and that command takes several minutes.

If I'm able to quick test if the lock fail has fallen out of sync I can build it into the bash environment to notify every command. Similar to how people like their `git status` to be built into their bash prompt.

Further more this makes sense in CI to make sure it does sneak it's way into the stable branch.

Comment: I assume you use some sort of version control system (for instance Git). Besides the composer.json file, do you commit composer.lock as well? Or is it being ignored?

Comment: Why not add a check to your CI pipelines that block merges in this case? Also, are you sure this problem is in any way related to [tag:bash]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For composer < 1.3.0

Extending from @Domster, the solution in pure bash:

```
COMPOSER_IN_SYNC=$(expr "`cat composer.lock | grep '"hash":' | cut -d'"' -f4`" = "`md5sum composer.json | cut -d ' ' -f 1`")
```

`$COMPOSER_IN_SYNC` will be `0` or `1` respectively.

Comment: See my comment to Domster's solution below.  This used to work until composer v1.3.0-RC, which removed 'hash' property.

Answer (score 28):

on newer versions (I suppose 1.3+) you can run the following:

```
$ composer validate --no-check-all --no-check-publish
```

Which might output something like this (with a catchable error exit code):

> ./composer.json is valid for simple usage with composer but has strict
> errors that make it unable to be published as a package: See
> https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md for details on the schema
> The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
> composer.json, it is recommended that you run `composer update`.

Answer (score 12):

> For composer < 1.3.0

Yes, there is a way to check for this very quickly.

The "out-of-date" check is based on a hash of the `composer.json` contents, stored in the `composer.lock`. There's no salt, and it's a straight-forward hash of the contents, so it's very, very easy to do.

```
<?php

$lock = json_decode(file_get_contents('composer.lock'))->hash;
$json = md5(file_get_contents('composer.json'));

if ($lock !== $json) {
    echo "Lock file out of date\n";
    exit(1);
}

echo "Lock file up to date\n";
exit(0);
```

Comment: This was working great until composer v1.3.0-RC (https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/1.3.0-RC), which removed the 'hash' property, leaving only 'content-hash', which is a bit more complicated to compute.  Here is the 'content-hash' computing method: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php#L72

Answer (score 8):

You can run

```
composer install --dry-run
```

> **--dry-run** Outputs the operations but will not execute anything (implicitly enables --verbose).

This won't change anything but will show the warning if not up to date. But it will still have to check the servers for new versions of your installed packages, so if you have many installed this might still take more than milli seconds. Anyway it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution for this by using `Sha1sum` and `Bash` script. We can run `composer install` only when `composer.json` or `composer.lock` files in your project are changed. I'm using this way for CI model.

1. Create a script file called `/usr/local/bin/git-update.sh` with the content below

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull -q --ff-only

repoName=${PWD##*/} # Get current folder name
checkFile=/tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12
if [[ ! -f $checkFile || $(sha1sum -c ${checkFile} 2> /dev/null | grep FAILED | awk "{print \$2}") == *"FAILED"* ]]; then
    composer install
    retVal=$?
    if [[ $retVal -eq 0 ]]; then
        sha1sum composer.json composer.lock > ${checkFile}
    fi
fi
```

Explanation:

- When running this script for the first time. `sha1sum` command output to `/tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12` with content looks similar below

```
 20379304c5944d13ef62f01edefa6ee3277a9e8c  composer.json
 afb0f4db50c81e0981e39dcb5b775fdd309319fe  composer.lock
```

- At the next runs, `sha1sum -c /tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12` is checking the SHA-1 checksum in the file. If your `composer.json` or `composer.lock` files are changed. The script runs `composer install` and adds a new SHA-1 checksum into the file.sha12. Otherwise, it does nothing.

2. Grant permission 700 for this script:

```
chmod 700 /usr/local/bin/git-update.sh
```

3. I'm assuming that you're storing your code project in a central platform (like GitHub). Every time you pull your code changes from the remote repository to you local machine. Just run script in the directory of your project. E.g.

```
cd /data/path/to-your-project && /usr/local/bin/git-update.sh
```