# How to test if PHP Composer dependencies are up to date with lockfile?

Tags: php, composer-php

How can I tell if the currently installed libraries in `vendor/` is up-to-date with the requirements from `composer.lock` (and `composer.json`)? I'm looking for a way to tell the developer that `composer install` is required to continue, e.g. after updating the codebase some dependencies might have changed in a way that breaks features unless updated.

I have seen similar questions such as [how-to-test-if-composer-lock-is-up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598089/how-to-test-if-composer-lock-is-up-to-date) but I'm not looking for a way to tell if `composer.lock` is up-to-date with `composer.json` but rather verifying that installed dependencies is up-to-date.

Comment: Have you check the --dry-run option ? According the doc : "This will simulate the installation and show you what would happen."

Comment: Is there a way to do that programatically or get stable output similar to `git --porcelain`?

Comment: In the doc they talks about the command "php composer.phar show -lo" to get the outdated vendors but I've just tried it and it seems to not working. https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md